# Best Approach SQL Server Calculated Column vs In Code Approach

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I currently have a CRUD ASP.NET MVC application that connects to SQL Server 2012. In the end the application exports data to a form. A field on the form is called `form number` which I would like to be `M-'Primary Key'`.

Would it be best to add the `M-` in the C# code or would a calculated column be the best approach? (add another column with `M-'PK'`).

If there are any other (better) options let me know!

**An example:**

Primary key: `1123`

**Output on form**

```
Form Number: M-1123
```

Comment: Would a calculated column work?

Comment: how this number is generated?

Comment: i assume your pk is an int value and by adding a 'M-' will make it a string value so the identity falls out ! I suggest creating a new coll and even better treat this in you application code

Comment: So do you want that M- prefix to be stored in the DB or just displayed to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See example in C:**

```
   private DataSet selectID(string studentId)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = "connecttoserverstring";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select 'M-' + cast(ID as varchar(10)) from table, conn);            
                SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@id", studentId);
                }
```

Even that the id is a int we cast it into a `varchar` so we can `concatenate` it with the 'M-' or what ever you want !
**Simple example of the output is** : 
- run this in SQL Server.

```
select 'M-' + cast(1 as varchar(10));
```

Comment: happy to help :) ! Up_One for me ! kkk